# Environment variable in nextjs deployed with heroku

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, next.js

Environment variable in nextjs deployed with heroku.

Code file ...\trcode\trapp.env.local has:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_CODER_MESSAGE="This is a test"`

Code file ...\trcode\trapp\pages\index.js has:

`<h2>Message from the coder: {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CODER_MESSAGE}</h2>`

Heroku settings, config vars, has:

`**KEY** NEXT_PUBLIC_CODER_MESSAGE **VALUE** I hope you enjoy the site!`

Locally and production both show "This is a test". I searched existing questions and read the nextjs docs but cannot seem to find out what I am doing wrong.